# Git has lost previous merges and says the branches have no changes, despite their being clear differences

Tags: git, github

We use git (hosted on GitHub) for our code repo.

We have a development branch, code is written in feature branches forked from dev, then merged into dev (using a PR). Releasing to live involves merging dev into live.

Increasingly over the past month, I'm noticing previously merged features are missing from dev and live. I can see the merged PR with the changes, but those changes aren't in dev. Oddly, when I compare the branch with dev, it says 'no changes' despite the fact that I can see the code present in the branch and missing in dev.

I'm not sure what caused this or how to proceed. I don't want to have to go through every feature the team has merged in the last month to see if it's present; even if I find missing ones, I can't re-merge them as git thinks they have no changes.

Looking at similar questions points to the `--ours` or `--force` arguments when pushing, but we've not used these AFAIK.

How can I recover or re-merge the missing features?

Comment: One explanation is that the changes were reverted after the PR was completed. It's common, when reverting a commit, to keep the default commit message which begins with "Revert...". Maybe you could search for that.

Comment: A second possibility, is that developers, when getting conflicts, are blindly choosing, "Keep ours" and blowing over other developer's work. You could prove this by seeing PRs after the one in question that undoes changes in a previous PR without mentioning the changes were intentionally reverted. This takes a little more sleuthing to find. (And this would be a horrible way to resolve conflicts, and means more training is required.)

Comment: Thanks @TTT, that's interesting. We did do a revert, but it should have just reverted one merge.

Is there a way of re-merging the missing branches? (except the one we had to revert?)

Comment: you said, "**should** have just reverted one merge." Maybe it reverted more than just one PR? Note using the `git revert` command only works on one commit, which could be a merge commit to undo multiple commits brought in by that merge. But it would be hard to accidentally revert multiple merge commits (to undo multiple PRs). Unless by chance your PRs use fast-forward sometimes and have a merge commit other times? Then reverting a merge commit could accidentally revert other PRs, if for example you reverted to parent 2 instead of parent 1.

Comment: Anyway, the normal way to fully undo a revert is to "revert the revert".

Comment: If you are left with some branches that you can't figure out why the changes are gone (so you have no revert to revert), then to remerge them you need to change the commit IDs so they can be brought in again. You could do that by rebasing the branch (either onto the target or in-place with the `-f` or `--no-ff` flag which will do nothing except rewrite those commit IDs, or you could squash the commits into one new commit ID, etc.

Comment: For fun I'm going to make a prediction. If you have a branch that you can't find a revert for, and if you rewrite the commit IDs on that branch and attempt to re-merge it, I predict you will have some conflicts, and the commits you end up conflicting with might be the ones that messed up the merge conflict resolution in the first place, as described by my second comment above.

Comment: I'll note that you can supply multiple hash IDs (or a range of commits) to `git revert` (same as for `git cherry-pick`), hence contradicting one sub-claim from @TTT above, but overall I'd make the same bet: someone mis-merged by carelessly resolving conflicts with a "keep mine" operation. Note that such mistakes are a little tricky to find with `git log` or `git blame` since they're not in the merged result.

Comment: There's a new / upcoming feature in Git in which it will be able to re-perform merges to detect merge commits whose result is not the same as an automerge. This feature, once it's generally available, will be hugely helpful here.

Comment: @torek good point about reverting multiple commits in one revert command. Interesting upcoming feature too!